# Nagios - Custom Report Generation

Tags: nagios, nms

I want to generate a custom report in "Nagios-3.2.0". I have defined the work-hours in "timeperiods.cfg" as follows:

## 'workhours' timeperiod definition

define timeperiod {

```
timeperiod_name 0800-2000
alias       full time

monday      08:00-20:00
tuesday     08:00-20:00
wednesday   08:00-20:00 
thursday    08:00-20:00
friday      08:00-20:00
saturday    08:00-20:00
}
```

Now, if I replace "saturday" with "2010-03-27" or "march 27" as shown below:

## 'workhours' timeperiod definition

define timeperiod {

```
timeperiod_name 0800-2000
alias       full time

monday      08:00-20:00
tuesday     08:00-20:00
wednesday   08:00-20:00 
thursday    08:00-20:00
friday      08:00-20:00
2010-03-27      08:00-20:00
}
```

Nagios is **not generating report** for the given date (2010-03-27).

How can I modify "timeperiods.cfg" so that I can generate reports for the given dates ?

Answer (score 0):

have you reviewed this?
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#timeperiod

I think you might have some luck trying other naming conventions.

Comment: Yes, I have already reviewed the above link, but did not get any success.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the timeperiod_name to a non numneric name.
eg "eightoeight"